# How to omit non-integer x-axis ticks in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The following figure has annoying x ticks at 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5.  Non-integer values have no interpretation for my purpose.

[image: Figure with ugly x-axis ticks]

> **Question**:  How can I get pgfplots to exclude non-integer x-axis ticks?

I realise I could do this via `xtick={0,...,3}`, but in larger cases, say with `xtick={0,...,100}`, the ticks would overlap.  So, this approach is not "flexible".

Ideally, I'd like to leave everything alone, except get rid of non-integer x-axis ticks if they arise.

Here's a minimum working example (it, of course, requires the standalone class and pgfplots package to run):

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar=0,xlabel={$\lambda$},ylabel={$\#\{\prec:\Lambda(G,\prec)=\lambda\}$},ymin=0,height=2in,width=4in]
    \addplot[blue!50,bar width=0] coordinates {
      (0,2)
      (1,4)
      (2,6)
      (3,12)
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide an MWE? I don't get the packages/tikz-subpackages that fast, that you are using, but i think, something like `xtick={0,25,...,100}`, i.e. the second number to specify the step width should work (and is flexible as requested).

Comment: Added MWE; the above compiles on my computer.

Comment: I missed (after a longish work day) the pgfplots in my first approach.

Answer (score 7):

So I tried my approach mentioned in the comment, here's the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[xtick={0,1,...,3},ybar=0,xlabel={$\lambda$},ylabel={$\#\{\prec:\Lambda(G,\prec)=\lambda\}$},ymin=0,height=2in,width=4in]
        \addplot[blue!50,bar width=0] coordinates {
          (0,2)
          (1,4)
          (2,6)
          (3,12)
        };
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image: plot].

You can change the `1` in `{0,1,...,3}` into a `2` to get just `0` and `2` with ticks, which demonstrates that for your question concerning `{0,...,100}` something like `{0,20,...,100}` would be quite nice and works fine.

**Edit:** Just as a note, because it might be of interest for others. Of course that also works the other way around, so `{0,.25,...,3}` or `{0,.5,...,3}` enforces noninteger values, though the first one looks quite dense.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! It's always best to strip code down to a *minimum*. For images, you can use the `standalone` documentclass, and note that `pgfplots` loads `tikz`- do you need the `amsmath` package for your example?

Comment: I wasn't sure, due to `\lambda` and `\prec` so i added that just to be sure. Of cource one could also use `standalone` I'll keep that in mind for next time. Sometimes I'm just leazy, and i had such an nMWE (nearly minimal, due to `scrartcl`) already opened in an editor ;)

Comment: Thanks for that; it is indeed a solution to the problem.  It would mean, however, that I would need to compute an appropriate separation between ticks in other instances (finding the separation would be possible via experimentation).

Comment: What would be better for your convenience? If you know the number of ticks (say `\x`) you could easily compute the stepsize. If you know neither - well that's what your example above does: Take something that fits nicely. Whether there is something, that ommits non-integers and takes itself something nicely - I don't know.